# How do i copy a project and build to the new one in Xamarin Form

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am a new Xamarin developer and i'm going to copy a old project and based on it to create a new app with new project,

but after deploy to my android phone and i saw it replaced the old one,

May anyone teach me the correct step to copy a project and change it as well?

Thanks.

Comment: The reason is because of the apps package name usually written like so `com.example.app`. All you need to do is duplicate the application and change the package name. I'm sure this isn't best practise but it is a solution

Comment: Thanks a lot! you are the best!